# How to see the result or output of data I used?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Good day! I just wanna ask. I have a drop down menu code in html, I want this code to see the results of a particular selection in drop down menu.
How? For Example I have a drop down menu and it's called grade level the content in this Drop down menu is from Grade 7-Grade 12 in my current page.

Now all I want is when I select a particular grade level in my current page (e.g I choose Grade 7) and I clicked Next, I will get directed from next page which is CStep3.php with the result like "This is your tuition fee in Grade 7 is $1000."

P.S sorry if my English is so bad.

[image]

Comment: use `$_GET` or  `$_POST`

Comment: On `CStep3.php` grab the value through $_POST. Now if you want to fetch data through database then send that value to database query and get the result. Or directly on the basis of the value of `$_POST` show hard-code results.

Comment: can I get step by step tutorial sir?  Cause I'm very confused. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PHP to handle HTTP request
For example index.php

```
<form action="CStep3.php" method="post">
  <select name="grade">
     .
     .
    <option value="7">Grade 7</option>
     .
     .
  </select>
</form>
```

CStep3.php file:

```
<?php
$grade = $_POST['grade']
//Query your tution fee using mysql
//$tution = mysqli...
echo "This is your tution fee for grade " . $grade . ":" .$tution

//if you dont have database connection
$grade = $_POST['grade'];
$tution = null;
if ($grade == 7) {
   $tution = 10000;
} elseif ($grade == 8) {
   $tution = 20000;
} else {
   $tution = 30000;
}
echo "This is your tution fee for grade " . $grade . ":" .$tution;
?>
```

Comment: is it possible to echo the data in php without database sir?? I know that I really need database to show my output but I wanna try for now what is the output looked like for now.

Comment: @Cent: you can hardcode the data, this way you don't need a database connection to show the data. You can use `if else` statement to change the `$tution` value. I edited the answer to show you how to do that

Comment: Hi sir @catcon, I tried your code and it is working  but how do I make it continues from grade 7 to grade 12? I have 12 options to pick in drop down menu and all of them have different tuition fees. thanks 